# How to add inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I made append with jquery so whoever click button adds more input where you can write number in it and i want to sum all of those input values also there are two values added by me which are important

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#square').on('click', '#add', function() {
    var value = $('#addmore').val();
    var html = value + '<input id="inp3" class="number"><br>';
    $('#secondary').append(html);
  })
  $("#secondary").on("click", "#sum", function() {
    // I WANT HELP HERE
    console.log(total);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <h1>summary</h1>
  <div id="secondary">
    Your daily salary: <input id="salary" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"> <input id="addmore"><button id="add">add more</button><br> Your business income daily <input id="income" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"><br>
    <button id="sum">summarise</button>
    <input type="number" class="gl" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: missing `.val()` in `parseInt($(".inp"))` should be `parseInt($(".inp").val())`

Comment: just fixed i wrote it wrong

Comment: what do you want to add ? add an example and what output do you expect

Answer (score 0):

**[1]** id should be unique so don't use same id for more than one element .. You're using `id="inp3"` with appended inputs so the id will duplicate

**[2]** You need to loop through inputs to get the SUM .. you can add the same class for all inputs you want to sum them or you can use `$(".inp , .number")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#square').on('click', '#add', function() {
    var value = $('#addmore').val();
    var html = value + '<input class="number"><br>';
    $('#secondary').append(html);
  })
  $("#secondary").on("click", "#sum", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".inp , .number").each(function(){
      total += parseInt($(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0);
    });
    console.log(total);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <h1>summary</h1>
  <div id="secondary">
    Your daily salary: <input id="salary" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"> <input id="addmore"><button id="add">add more</button><br> Your business income daily <input id="income" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"><br>
    <button id="sum">summarise</button>
    <input type="number" class="gl" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[3]** I can't know the purpose of using `value` in `var html = value + '<input class="number"><br>';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over all the `.number` inputs, adding the values to a total.

```
  $("#secondary").on("click", "#sum", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#secondary .number").each(function() {
      if (this.value) {
        total += parseInt(this.value);
      }
    }
    console.log(total);
  })
```